# Flutter + Firebase Cloud Functions - How to get data from HttpsCallableResult

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-functions

I have written a simple cloud function that returns an id that is saved within my Cloud Firestore database.

The cloud function looks like this:

```
exports.getWinkert = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

    return admin.firestore().collection('users').doc('hash').get()
    .then(snapshot => {
        const winkertId = snapshot.wwinkert
        return { id: winkertId };
    })
})
```

This function is called from my flutter app with this code:

```
Future _getValues() async {
    final HttpsCallable callable = CloudFunctions.instance.getHttpsCallable(
      functionName: "getWinkert",
    );
    dynamic resp = await callable.call(<String, dynamic>{
      "name": "wwinkert",
    });
    print(resp.toString());
  }
```

Upon calling the function, I get this result:

```
I/flutter ( 8253): Instance of 'HttpsCallableResult'
```

Question: How do I get my data from the HttpsCallableResult instance in Dart?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Greets,
Raul

Answer (score 4):

A quick look through this documentation:

https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/cloud_functions

reveals that one can get data by adding .data to the HttpsCallableResult object.

.
.
.

My apologies :D

Comment: To clear thing up for other users, you can get the id like this resp.data['id'];

Comment: This link is broken